# Need to access all the label values of an input and then truncate after the second underscore

Tags: jquery, each

i have a page where the markup looks something like this. i’m trying to use jQuery’s each. function to access the value of each label and then truncate after the second underscore.

so for example, this value  "M_1010_Lilac" would be changed to this value  “Lilac”

```
<div class="threads-swatch-wrapper"><input type="hidden" name="descriptive[51]" value="M_1010_Coral_Cloud"  class="swatch-descriptive-name" />
<input type="radio" name="id[51]" value="2564" id="attrib-51-2564" class="threads-radio-btn" />
<label class="attribsRadioButton two thread-opts" for="attrib-51-2564">M_1010_Coral_Cloud<br />
<img src="images/attributes/Vineyard_Merino_Wool/M_1010_Coral_Cloud.jpg" alt="" width="260" height="320" /></label></div>

<div class="threads-swatch-wrapper"><input type="hidden" name="descriptive[51]" value="M_1010_Lilac"  class="swatch-descriptive-name" />
<input type="radio" name="id[51]" value="2565" id="attrib-51-2565" class="threads-radio-btn" /><label class="attribsRadioButton two thread-opts" for="attrib-51-2565">M_1010_Lilac<br />
<img src="images/attributes/Vineyard_Merino_Wool/M_1010_Lilac.jpg" alt="" width="260" height="320" /></label></div>
```

i’ve tried various things but so far nothing is working. 
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post the various things you tried, and explain in which ways they're not working.

Comment: $.each($('label.thread-opts'), function() { 
str = this.text();
});

Comment: str = str.split("_");
nuString = str[2];
if(indexOf(str[3])) {
  nuString = str[2] + ' ' + str[3];
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have your answer here for you. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1x3sgfhn/3/)

Probably not the prettiest or most efficient answer available but it works.

```js
$('label').each(function() {
    
    var str = $(this).text(), img;
    var img_str = $(this).html();
    var word, uh, x = [], z = 0; 
    
    for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {
        if ( str.charAt(i) === '_' ) {
            x[z] = i;   
            z++;
        }
    }

    if ( img_str.search('<') != -1 ) {    
        img = img_str.substring(img_str.search('<'), img_str.length);
    } else {
        img = '';
    }
    
    if ( x.length > 2 ) {
        uh = str.substring(x[1]+1, str.length);
        word = uh.replace('_', ' ');
    } else {
        word = str.substring(x[1]+1, str.length);   
    }
    
    $(this).html(word + img);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>M_1010_Coral_Cloud<br />
<img src="images/attributes/Vineyard_Merino_Wool/M_1010_Coral_Cloud.jpg" alt="" width="260" height="320" /></label> <br />
<label>M_1010_Lilac</label> <br />
<label>M_1010_Flower</label>
```

Comment: thank you, that works except for some bizarre reason it deletes the image tag entirely from the mark-up! i wish i could send a link to the dev site but i can't

Comment: Oh I didn't see the image was part of the label! I can update my answer soon.

Comment: super cool, great job! thanks for helping me learn. i've really learned something here